# SQL Server Recursive CTE - Tag Duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I trying to loop through a hierarchical data set using recursive CTEs in SQL Server and I am running into some problems.

Here is a visual representation of the data I am working with:

[image]

Basically when I recursively loop through the data I want to tag any duplicates with an identifier if it exists more than once (basically just a number that is the count of how many time it exists to differentiate it from the others).

I am currently able to loop through correctly, keep track of the level, and the unique path but I do not know how I can append a tag when the item is duplicated.

Here is the current output in a tabular view:

[image]

Here is a SQL Fiddle with sample schema and data to test.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fcbf51/2

Thanks for any help.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I am confused... I did not post an image of code.  My screenshots are the visual representations of my data.  You could not paste that into any compiler, its meant to be a visual aid to understand my problem. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any problem with these images, not the images of code.

Comment: I can't make heads or tails of what you are trying to do here. Your sample data is so generic it is nearly indecipherable.

Comment: I've missed the link to sqlfiddle. Downvote retracted (had to edit the question to do that, but that's OK because I fixed a typo)

Comment: Sample data is best served as DDL+DML, desired results is best served as formatted text. Anyway, since you have linked to sqlfiddle that's OK. Now to the question itself - You do not have a column to order your results by. This means that the order on which the results are returned is arbitrary and is not to be trusted. Therefor, You can't count the instances of a material up to a single row in the result set, because nothing guarantees the order of the result set.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fcbf51/13 is this what you are looking for?